# How to calculate quantiles with NA in data in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do RFM Analysis on my data where the Recency(number of days) containS NA.
Tried the code below:

```
rawdata1$Rsegment <- findInterval(rawdata1$R,quantile(rawdata1$R, c(0.0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0,na.rm= TRUE)))
```

and getting the following error:

> Error in quantile.default(rawdata1$R, c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, na.rm = TRUE)) : 
>     missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only just begun to learn R myself, but it looks as though your na.rm is bundled in with your concatenation. Try this:

```
rawdata1$Rsegment <- findInterval(rawdata1$R,quantile(rawdata1$R, c(0.0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0), na.rm= TRUE))
```

Comment: @AsOlivieri..How I will sort rawdata$R in ascending order and then assign quintile? Any help with that

Comment: You might want to do that in two separate steps. Sort. Then get quantiles. Not sure, really.